# error while passing input value to the next page

Tags: php, html

below is the original code, and

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    

    <div class="slider-container">
      <form action="asd.php" method="GET">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="slider">
      </form>
        <div id="selector">
          <div class="SelectBtn1"></div>
          <div id="SelectValue"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Progressbar"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextcontainer">
      <a href="asd.php" class="result">Result &raquo;</a>
    </div>
```

the asd.php

```
<body>
  <div class="result-head">
    <h1 class="main-title ng-binding">Your excrement..</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="result-container">
    <h1 class="area">can support annually<?php echo $_REQUEST['slider'];?></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

I made html file and php file, and I tried to get response from the survey and try to show it in the next page(asd.php)

However, when I input and surf the next page, it shows pure code like the picture. What did I do wrong?
[image]

Comment: Is that the original code? where is the submit button? how do you send the data to asp.php page?

Comment: @cooper I thought the last three lines would do the submit job. Is it not correct?

Comment: you do not need any submit button to run it,  but you are only viewing not really executing the script. is your webserver running? php module enabled? run your script within your webserver environment..something like : http://localhost/yourscript.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the attribute name instead of the attribute id because that is how it is passed on. For example you could do

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    

    <div class="slider-container">
      <form action="asd.php" method="GET">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="slider" name="slider">
      </form>
        <div id="selector">
          <div class="SelectBtn1"></div>
          <div id="SelectValue"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Progressbar"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nextcontainer">
      <a href="asd.php" class="result">Result &raquo;</a>
    </div>
```